# Android notification with progress bar issues

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar

I'm using [link](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/show-progressbar-in-notification-area-like-google-does-when-downloading-from-android/)  tutorial

to show a notification with a progress bar.

But when I run this demo I can't see progress bar

I use API 8

Is there any problem?

How can I do this?

Note: Before I post ,I did search some topic in this forum. Everyone said OK so what's the problem here ? I guess may be notification can't work fine with API8.

Can anyone help me figure out this? thanks

Comment: Notification can work in API 8, but if you post some code that you have then it will make getting help easier.

Comment: I just downloaded demo project from https://github.com/nheid/unitedcoders-android/downloads    . I didn't do anything and I run it and click on Status bar it didn't show progress bar.Can you help me check that code?

Comment: Do you have the progress dialog layout file that it references in your xml?

Comment: Yep,I have,Thanks for your answers. I found the reason.Code in demo project call finish() DownloadProgress activity when start a progress thread that why progress bar couldn't show.